# jQuery: Append numeric value to existing ID with

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is there any simple way to append numeric value to all existing child DOMs ID like described below:

**Existing DOMs:**

```
<div class="contacts" id="contact"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact"></div>
...
```

**Desired DOMs:**

```
<div class="contacts" id="contact1"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact2"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact3"></div>
...
```

**Existing code JS:**

```
var additional = 0;
$(".contact").each(function() {
  additional++;
  $(this).prop("id", $(this).attr("id")+additional);
});
```

**Existing code return something like this:**

```
<div class="contacts" id="contact11111"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact2222"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact333"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact44"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact5"></div>
....
```

Comment: your code looks fine. where did you put each function??

Comment: Should it not be `$(".contacts").each(function()` i.e. contacts not contact

Comment: @Yahya: may be typo while sharing.

Comment: Can be simplified :) `$(".contacts").attr("id", function(idx) { return this.id + (idx+1); });`

Comment: i think problem with you are having multiple loops i your original code. you only have to go to this loop once. put a counter and check perform if it set "id" for index 1 then it should not go to this loop second time.

Comment: 1st iteration contact1 in second contact1+1 means contact11 then  contact11 + 1 means contact111 and so on...

Comment: Can update code woth how many iterations you are having outer this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you are getting above DOM is when you are iterating over each function when every time a new element is added. something like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
   $('body').append('<div class="contacts" id="contact"></div>');
   var additional = 0;
   $(".contact").each(function() {
    additional++;
    $(this).prop("id", $(this).attr("id")+additional);
   });
 }
```

which results in DOM to :

```
<div class="contacts" id="contact11111"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact2222"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact333"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact44"></div>
<div class="contacts" id="contact5"></div>
```

Correct way to get the desired markup is to iterate over element when all the elements are added:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
   $('body').append('<div class="contacts" id="contact"></div>');
}//after appending 5 elements
$(".contacts").attr("id",function(index) {
    return this.id + (index + 1) 
});
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that my script was placed in wrong iteration but in practice it is much complicated than example I represented. As the matter of fact, I managed to fix it by moving jQuery code out of initial iteration (which creates DOMs) and setting up two new iterations (first which count and assign parent DOMs and second which only chage IDs of child DOMs).

Answer (score 0):

You only have to do is

```
 $(".contact").each(function(i,item) {
        //Reset Attribute id with new value
        $(item).attr("id", $(item).attr("id")+(i+1));
 });
```

Comment: It's not an option as "contact" is also generic id; I need to append to previous ID whatever that ID was.

Comment: just change with $(item)

Comment: No need to create two jQuery objects per iteration: `$(item).attr("id", $(item).attr("id")+(i+1));` -> `this.id = this.id + (i + 1);`

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right. I think problem with so many iteration is their in his code so every time this op performs and he get contact11111. contact2222. so on...