Why is my :nth-child not working on my ID selector
I have a wordpress site where the divs are ID's and cant just make the one background color black. I have tried :nth-child(1) and :nt-child(3) but its not working. And I cant change the ID's as its part of the theme.
Just want to make the 1st one and last one have a background color of black. Even tried


#page-services:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #000;
}
<div id="page-services">
  <div class="divider-xl"> text </div>
</div>

<div id="page-services">
  <div class="divider-xl"> text </div>
</div>

<div id="page-services">
  <div class="divider-xl"> text </div>
</div>




I've made a code snippet from your code, but with the code posted I can't reproduce your issue. Please revise

Cause more ID selectors with same name are not semantic.
Use:
Using nth-child:

HTML:

<div id="container">
<div class="box" id="box1">text</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">text</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">text</div>
</div>

CSS:

#container .box(nth-child)....

or

#container div(nth-child)....


How would that apply? There is only one child in each #container

I'm not the OP, but there is no issue as pointed out in the comments. This is answer is just incorrect

But it works in code snippet above…

Than you can edit it in css… straight for this unique class…

If you want to use nth-child, it must be in the same container.

I have tried doing it with the unique class, elementor-element... but that didnt work. Would you happen to know how to change the ID with a Class with Jquery. Is that even possible?

Just select it in CSS: .elementor-element-936006f #page-services {your code}…

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266597/jquery-append-numeric-value-to-existing-id-with

But nth-child will never work in this case… you must style it in css by unique class

thanks so much that worked! Appreciate your help @DIGIPOWER.

this is because nth:child selector is not ment to be used for IDs. The point is, you can have multiple elements with same class but element IDs need to be unique and specific to one and only one element. (Multiple elements with same ID is not valid html)
